how can I represent the square tilted or rotated in 3D space?
I tried so much to get square the same graph as shown In the image but I am unable to do that. Please help me what can I do to get the desired square in latex tikzpicture.

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3.0]
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=center,
 minor tick={-12,-11,...,12},
    view={45}{45},
    xmin=-10, xmax=10, ymin=-10, ymax=10, zmin=-10, zmax=10,
]
\draw[variable=\Vt, smooth, domain=-20:16, samples=500] 
    plot ({(8*\Vt/30)*cos(10*\Vt)}, {(8*\Vt/30)*sin(10*\Vt)}, {21*\Vt/30});
\draw[thick] (0.6,2,-1.9) circle (2);
% Draw a square outside the circle
\draw[thick] (0.6+4,-2-3,-1.9) -- (0.6+3,2+3,-1.9) -- (0.6-4,2+3,-1.9) -- (0.6-3,-2-3,-1.9) -- cycle;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


There are no issues - your code looks good. You need to ask about one thing at a time. There are several things that are not the same as the image - what aspect is causing you problems? Please also edit your title to reflect your question.

@hpekristiansen I edited the title of the question. I try to make the square as shown in the given image. My drawn square does not look the same. Please can you help me with this

In my view the best is to forget 3D and perceive the 2D drawing as it is. Then you see: a) a diamond, b) 3 rotated axes of different lengths. That's all. No rotataion, no transformation, just 2D perception.

@MS-SPO I have tried this but it didn't fix the square and also destroyed the shape of the curve.

Does your code show this?

@MS-SPO If you're asking about the attached code then it's in 3d, but if about the 2d then I tried it after your suggestion. It didn't work for me.

@MS-SPO I want to keep the curve and circle as it is because it is almost the same as the given picture shown

Assuming that the square shows the span of two vectors and the third vector is the cross product.
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={
ax=0; ay=1; az=0;
bx=-0.5; by=1.8; bz=-0.2;
size=2;
cx=ay*bz-az*by;
cy=az*bx-ax*bz;
cz=ax*by-ay*bx;
}]
\begin{axis}[
anchor=origin,
xmin=-3, xmax=3,
ymin=-3, ymax=3,
zmin=-3, zmax=3,
axis lines=center,
clip=false,
tick label style={font=\tiny},
]
\draw[gray]
({size*(-ax-bx)},{size*(-ay-by)},{size*(-az-bz)}) --
({size*(-ax+bx)},{size*(-ay+by)},{size*(-az+bz)}) --
({size*(+ax+bx)},{size*(+ay+by)},{size*(+az+bz)}) --
({size*(+ax-bx)},{size*(+ay-by)},{size*(+az-bz)}) -- cycle
(size*ax,size*ay,size*az) -- (-size*ax,-size*ay,-size*az)
(size*bx,size*by,size*bz) -- (-size*bx,-size*by,-size*bz);
\draw[red, ->, thick] (0,0,0) -- (ax,ay,az);
\draw[green, ->, thick] (0,0,0) -- (bx,by,bz);
\draw[blue, ->, thick] (0,0,0) -- (cx,cy,cz);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Assuming a square is wanted at xy plane with z=-1.9 as the circle:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=center,
minor tick={-12,-11,...,12},
view={45}{45},
xmin=-10, xmax=10, ymin=-10, ymax=10, zmin=-10, zmax=10,
]
\draw[variable=\Vt, smooth, domain=-20:16, samples=500] 
plot ({(8*\Vt/30)*cos(10*\Vt)}, {(8*\Vt/30)*sin(10*\Vt)}, {21*\Vt/30});
\draw[thick] (0.6,2,-1.9) circle (2);
% Draw a square outside the circle
\draw[thick] (0.6+4,-2-3,-1.9) -- (0.6+3,2+3,-1.9) -- (0.6-4,2+3,-1.9) -- (0.6-3,-2-3,-1.9) -- cycle;
\draw[thick, red] (0.6,2,-1.9) ++(axis direction cs:-3,-3,0) -- ++(axis direction cs:6,0,0) -- ++(axis direction cs:0,6,0) -- ++(axis direction cs:-6,0,0) -- cycle ;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



It is different from the given picture. if you can compile my given code then you will understand my point. The square produced is on one side of the circle but I want it should be at the center of the square as shown in the given image. that is the main problem I am facing. Please can you address it
